# Ansible, npm, and the --save-dev flag

Tags: npm, ansible

I'm trying to use ansible to provision karma testing servers for jenkins using the karma-phantomjs-launcher plugin. I'm hoping to avoid using shellscripts of the "exec npm install" format.

The trouble is that the phantomjs plugin requires the `--save-dev` flag to be used on install. I'm looking to use the `--save-dev` flag from npm, but the ansible npm module does not appear to have a way to pass these flags to the actual npm command that it runs.

Is this possible, or should I just resort to using ansible's command module to run `npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the same problem as yours, but I had a similar problem, trying to get npm to use proxies from within ansible.  I found that you can run npm commands, and hence run npm config commands.  I assume there is an npm config command for `save-dev` there is for most things.

In my case I setup a task inside a role, which was responsible for setting up apache, and npm (and installing npm's bower package).

This is the snipped from my task (remember this is inside a role, not a direct task, and it follows a yum with command, which is passed a list of packages, including npm).

```
- name: Setup NPM HTTP Proxy
  become: True
  command: npm config set proxy "{{http_proxy}}"
  when: (http_proxy is defined) and (not http_proxy == '') and (node_modules.stat.exists == False)

- name: Clear NPM HTTP Proxy Setting
  become: True
  command: npm config rm proxy
  when: (http_proxy is defined) and (http_proxy == '') and (node_modules.stat.exists == False)

- name: Setup NPM HTTPS Proxy
  become: True
  command: npm config set https-proxy "{{https_proxy}}"
  when: (https_proxy is defined) and (not https_proxy == '') and (node_modules.stat.exists == False)

- name: Clear NPM HTTPS Proxy Setting
  become: True
  command: npm config rm https-proxy
  when: (https_proxy is defined) and (https_proxy == '') and (node_modules.stat.exists == False)

- name: Disable NPM strict SSL mode
  become: True
  command: npm config set strict-ssl false
  when: (http_proxy is defined) and (not http_proxy == '') and (node_modules.stat.exists == False)

- name: Clear NPM strict SSL mode Setting (if no http_proxy)
  become: True
  command: npm config rm strict-ssl
  when: (http_proxy is defined) and (http_proxy == '') and (node_modules.stat.exists == False)

- name: Setup NPM to use http:// version of the registry
  become: True
  command: npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
  when: (http_proxy is defined) and (not http_proxy == '') and (node_modules.stat.exists == False)

- name: Install Bower
  become: True
  shell: >
         umask 022; npm install bower chdir=/usr/local/lib
  when: node_modules.stat.exists == False
```

Apologies if this doesn't help